# Unable to sign apk file using jarsigner

Tags: android, command-line, apk, jarsigner, jar-signing

I am signing my apk using the below command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore mykeystore.keystore myApp.apk aliasname
```

The log ends with

```
.
.
.
signing: org/achartengine/image/zoom-1.png
signing: org/achartengine/image/zoom_in.png
signing: org/achartengine/image/zoom_out.png
signing: LICENSE.txt
signing: assets/cpwrUEM-instr-runtime.properties
jar signed.
```

But when I run the verification command:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myApp.apk
```

I get the below error:

```
jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for res/drawable-hdpi-v4/btn_large.png
```

Most of the forums mentions that when we get the above error message we should resign the jar by adding -digestalg SHA1. But I already have that and still get the same exception.

On trying to install on a device, I get the message

```
There is a problem parsing the package.
```

### UPDATE:

On changing the algorithm from SHA1 to SHA-256 it stills give me the same exception but this time on a xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if the apk you are signing is originally unsigned or not. If not, export the unsigned version using the Android Tools in your IDE.